# Visual Basic 6 vbp file corrupting randomly

Tags: vb6

Ok, I know this is a very old product so I'm hoping there are still a few of us old timers still out there who can help me.
Internally we have several old systems which are in the process of being migrated to c# however routine work is still required within them.

We have had a problem for quite some time and it appears to be getting worse, in fact it was mostly noticed since upgrading to Windows 10.

To give an example one project consists of the main application and 19 dll's all grouped within the project. Any part of the project can be compiled and works fine, but other times I can compile a dll and the dll vbp file gets corrupted.

Corruption could be...

**Duplication**

```
Reference=*\G{72F49028-2BDA-4107-9870-FA71E3F7DFA9}#3.3#0#..\..\..\..\..\DLLStore\VB6\Search.dll#
Reference=*\G{72F49028-2BDA-4107-9870-FA71E3F7DFA9}#3.3#0#..\..\..\..\..\DLLStore\VB6\Search.dll#
```

**Or incorrect reference guid**

```
Reference=*\G{72F6675-2BDA-4133-9778-FA71E3F7DE3}#1.2#0#..\windows\---\COMDLG32.OCX (I've forgotten the exact text)
Object={F9043C88-F6F2-101A-A3C9-08002B2F49FB}#1.2#0; COMDLG32.OCX
```

Removing the reference line fixes this.

I know I could mark the vbp to be read only and then keep changing it as required but I need to get to the bottom of what is causing it in the first place.

Any pointers are greatly received :-)

Comment: Regarding the `COMDLG32.OCX` entries - the `Object` line (normally) comes from adding the control to the project from the Toolbox Components dialog. The `Reference` line usually occurs from selecting the component from the Project-References dialog.  But, they are effectively mutually exclusive (at least for `COMDLG32.OCX`, at least for me), when it's added via either method above, trying to add it via the other dialog results in an error message.  So I have no suggestion as to how to get both in the vbp file at one time.

Comment: I have seen corruption from the VB6 IDE saving only a portion fo the VBP, but never duplication like this.  Can you pinpoint the action or moment in time when the problem gets introduced?

Comment: There are several projects so it is not unique to a project setup up or anything like that and the problem can occur in any of the projects (since windows 10). I can work without issue for days but as soon as I compile then close and reopen a project the issue creeps in but not every time (most). Another randomly occuring issue, if I have a project (A) pointing to test.dll file and compile the test.vbp (not grouped within a project (B) so standalone project) I need to close project (A) (obviously) but when I reopen project (A) it now points to the test.vbp project(B) and not the test.dll

Comment: Don't know how helpful this is but will share it. We have some large VB6 VBG groups and haven't seen corruption issues like this. Although we have 5 projects in a group not 19 so they aren't as large as yours.

Comment: What's causing this is unclear. Compiling DLLs on dev machine I never use but compile everything on a build server and shell `vb6.exe /make` like in [this script](https://github.com/wqweto/UcsFiscalPrinters/blob/master/scripts/build.bat).

Comment: Would recommend re-installing, try using a diff computer (with same code), try it on a virtual machine perhaps.  Since it is not a common occurrence, narrowing it down to something specific to that machine/install would be the first thing I'd try.  Once you know it works on other machines, and then you know it's machine specific. If you re-install VB6 and it still does it, it could be a HDD issue, an underlying OS or common DLL issue, or some such.  Try eliminating possibilities one by one and see if you can narrow down some more specifics to make it "fail".

Comment: Hi User51 - we have several dev machines the problem only really happens on windows 10 and mainly relates to far point spreadsheet dll's but no always. When compiling on an older windows 7 machine it appears ok. Its worth knowing that some dev pc were upgraded to windows 10 and some were clean install but both show the same issue. Theres something under windows 10 thats causing the problem but I just can't see what or how it impacts on the compiler.

Comment: We're having similar problems for years, we haven't found any solution :(